# Restrict access to AWS API Gateway only from specific domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, api-gateway

quick (maybe obvious) question.

I have an http API Gateway in AWS. I would like to restrict the access to the API gateway only from specific domain e.g. https://example.com
What mechanism is more appropriate to achieve this? Someone has suggested me CORS, but i am not sure about it, I was thinking on lambda authoriser that check the header origin?
Any suggestion appreciate!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you not sure about CORS ? Usually it's a good idea to stick to industry standards and in this case I believe CORS is the standard for this use case. Morever CORS is an option in API Gateway so it should be easy to implement.

Comment: @Alexandre_Bon thanks for your response. probably you are right and I am overthinking. My confusion is that CORS is a client side mechanism and does not provide server side access control, so potentially my API endpoint can be still access from somewhere else. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: This is true, however the origin header can be modified manually by a user, so you get the same problem in the end.

Comment: @Alexandre_Bon No. CORS is no defence. Rather, it's a mechanism for relaxing the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: @Domenico Your comment is correct. Neither the SOP nor CORS are substitute for server-side authorisation, if that's what you need.